# Ubuntu 13.04 apt-get and software center crashes after trying to install google-talkplugin

Tags: apt, software-center

For some reasons, the installation of Google talk failed and now I cannot install anything. First when I tried `apt-get`, I was asked to run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which went well, but still I get the following error when I try to install anything:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-talkplugin needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

If I try to reinstall `google-talkplugin`, Ubuntu Software Center cannot even start!
how can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If the problem still exists, then edit the `dpkg` status file

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Find the package in question, and remove everything that has anything to do with it, then save the file and restart your system.